# turning an array into an object using es6 map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I currently have the following data structure:

```
const bar = [
    {id:1, version:0, name:"test name A"},
    {id:2, version:0, name:"test name B"},
    {id:3, version:0, name:"test name C"}
];
```

And I need to turn it into this:

```
const foo = {
    1:{id:1, version:0, name:"test name A"},
    2:{id:2, version:0, name:"test name B"},
    3:{id:3, version:0, name:"test name C"}
};
```

The piece of code I actually have is this:

```
for(let i=0;len = bar.length; i< len;i++){
    foo[bar[i].id]= bar[i];
}
```

I've tried doing

```
bar.map((element,index)=>{
    const temporal = {[index]:element};
    foo = {...foo, temporal};
});
```

but I'm lost, any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want an object with numeric indices?

Comment: Are you talking about using `Array.map` or the new ES6 `Map` structure? There seems to be some confusion. Because you can just do `bar.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, o), new Map());` if you want the latter. `Array.map` has been around long before ES6.

Comment: @Andy - `new Map(Object.entries(bar));`

Comment: @adeneo I don't want to. It's a data structure I need to pass to an API.

Comment: @OriDrori, ha! I was just impressed with your code from earlier as you might have guessed. Kudos for keeping me on my toes. That was a great answer earlier btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` with `Object.assign()`

```js
const bar = [
    {id:1, version:0, name:"test name A"},
    {id:2, version:0, name:"test name B"},
    {id:3, version:0, name:"test name C"}
];

var result = bar.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, {[e.id]: e}), {});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
const
    bar = [{ id: 1, version: 0, name: "test name A" }, { id: 2, version: 0, name: "test name B" }, { id: 3, version: 0, name: "test name C" }],
    object = Object.assign(...bar.map(o => ({ [o.id]: o })));

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` returns an array, if you wanted to return an object, you could use `Array.reduce` instead

```js
const bar = [
    {id:1, version:0, name:"test name A"},
    {id:2, version:0, name:"test name B"},
    {id:3, version:0, name:"test name C"}
];

var foo = bar.reduce( (a,b,i) => (a[i+1] = b, a), {});

console.log(foo);
```

If you just need to reformat the data for sending it to an API, there's no need to create true clones of the objects with `Object.assign`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), aka fold or inject in general:

```
const bar = [
    {id:1, version:0, name:"test name A"},
    {id:2, version:0, name:"test name B"},
    {id:3, version:0, name:"test name C"}
];

bar.reduce((obj, e, i) => { obj[e.id] = e; return obj}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to use `forEach` which iterates over the array, but doesn't return an array as `map` does:

```
let foo = {};
bar.forEach((el, idx) => foo[idx+1] = el)
```